# Using NLP on web data (Indeed) without storing data after scraping by going directly through URL

Tags: python, nlp, screen-scraping

I have already made a python code using BeautifulSoup to scrape data from Indeed. This solution required to create a CSV file after scraping my data and then I could apply other functions on it.
But having a huge csv file is really time consuming and takes a lot of space for nothing. In fact, after I want to apply NLP functions on my Indeed data to find topics.

So, my idea was to give to my NLP function a URL so that it can search automatically in Indeed without having to go through a csv file. But I didn't find anything on the internet to do that. I feel like everyone use first a csv file and then apply NLP on it.

Do you know a tool/technique to solve my problem ?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "apply nlp"? Which framework or methods are you using, which units does it require, e.g. single documents or sentences? What is the chunk size of the data when you are scraping it, e.g. one document per URL call or multiple? Usually loading and saving the data is not the performance bottleneck, much more likely either the scraping or the text processing with your NLP framework is. Also generally making a very large amount of small requests tends to be slower and more prone to running into the websites anti-scraping measures than downloading a big chunk at once.

Comment: Can you show your process how you get the data into the CSV and how you get it from there and process it? There usually are a lot of optimization potentials for that as well when handling big files (e.g. avoiding loading the entire dataset into memory but rather processing it line by line and saving the results directly).

Comment: You can find the code here: https://github.com/MarieDouguet/Test
it's a bit old so maybe the tags are not the right ones but here is the idea of what I did...

Comment: What do you mean by processing lines by lines? Is it possible even if I want to get topics from my all page at the end? Or will my result be biaised?

Comment: I see, that script collects 50 job posting URLs with an average of 10 seconds wait time for the first 1000 results (so 20 chunks and an overall time of ~200s). Then it seems to go through all the collected URLs and get the description texts from each, with an average wait time of 5 seconds (so another ~5000s) which means that it has a wait time alone of ~86minutes + however long it takes the server to reply to all the requests + the rest of the code to run and save everything.

Comment: I really can't imagine that CSV plays any significant role in the run time of it, especially since that seems to be a pretty small dataset. The majority of the run time seems to come from how this is scraped. Is this long of a wait time really required? I can't imagine that the website is that easiely triggering anti-scraping mechanisms. If you just go to the result page and click through every job of the first 50 you would already be triggering it if it was that sensitive.

Comment: By "processing line by line" I was more talking about the CSV file. If you have truly giant CSV files (like hundreds of thousands of lines) it can make sense to iterate through the file and process things on the fly instead of reading the whole file into memory and then iterating over that loaded file.

Comment: If I put a shorter waiting time Indeed blocks my account. So, you recommend me to reduce the waiting time in case they don't block me ? And do you have a recommendation if I don't want to automatically store data in a csv ?
Do you know a better scraping method that do not required to go through HTML tags ?

Comment: I think CSV is generally a good way to locally store text data. You could just store the URLs instead of the actual texts (so only run the script until line 76), but then you need to use these URLs to retrieve the data during the analysis, which means you would have to put the wait times there, so I dont think that really improves things.

Comment: Usually scraping is against theses websites TOS so if their system detects you repeatedly you probably will get blocked, especially if you then continue to send a lot of requests, so you are right that its more likely to happen if you lower the wait time. As far as I see the script does NOT check if the response is an expected one or something else (e.g. the website showing a warning/captcha or a different response code). It just keeps on trying if the previous URL failed (see line 81). You could try to modify this part to stop sending requests when that happened.

Comment: Sadly there often is no better method than scraping the HTML if websites do not offer a proper API. You could read through https://developer.indeed.com/ but it doesnt sound to me like they offer free access to the job postings for anyone. An alternative would be to use a previously scraped, available dataset, but I'm not sure if that fits your purposes. Check out for example https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=indeed+job+in%3Adatasets.

Comment: I will check that ! Thanks a lot for all your answers :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.